# Difference between the meaning of "all young student" and "all young students"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Whole sentence is this:

> I firmly believe that graduating from a university is the goal of **all young student**.

If I use 'all young students,' has it different meaning than the earlier phrase quoted above?

Comment: What did the original quote intend to convey?

Comment: The sentence is not correct. it should end in either "... a young student" or "... all young students". You should ask about the difference between those.

Comment: @MrLister or "... any young student" or "... each young student" or "... every young student"

Comment: It does and it doesn't… "all young student" is a mistake and nothing more. You need "all young student*s*" with an "s" to make it plural or "A/any/each young student" without the "s', to show it's singular.

FYI, you ill find more help for such Questions anywhere like  English Language Learners.

Answer (score 0):

The last part is written wrong. It should be "**all young students**" since here the sentence is talking about many students. The correct sentence will be:

> I firmly believe that graduating from a university is the goal of **all
>   young students**.